Remove second "Day" column and Turn nulls to 0
I have the following query in MySQL:
set 
  @userid = '97c73a4d-11b2-4492-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX';
set 
  @lastdate = '2024-08-31';
SET 
  @sql = NULL;
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(
    DISTINCT CONCAT(
      'Count(CASE WHEN Checkedby = ''', 
      IFNULL(Checkedby, 0), 
      ''' THEN IFNULL(Checkedby,0) END) AS ''', 
      CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName), 
      ''''
    )
  ) INTO @sql 
FROM 
  Bookings B 
  JOIN USERINFO UI ON B.CheckedBy = UI.ID 
  left join tours T on T.TourID = B.TourID 
  left join Providers P on P.ProviderID = T.ProviderID;
SET 
  @sql = CONCAT (
    'SELECT  Y.*,X.*
 FROM (SELECT ifnull(F.DAY,0) as DAY, IFNULL(Count(B.Checkedby),0) as Total, ', 
    @sql, ' FROM ORDERS O inner join BOOKINGS B on O.ORDERID = B.OrderID 
    left JOIN 
  (SELECT day(ifnull(N.Checkin,0)) as DAY, Count(N.Checkin) as Total FROM 
  Bookings N group by day(ifnull(N.Checkin,0))) F on F.DAY = day(B.Checkin)
 WHERE year(B.Checkin)*1 = year(@lastdate) and month(B.Checkin)*1 = month(@lastdate)  and 
 (B.UserID = @userid) 
 GROUP BY F.DAY) X RIGHT JOIN (select day(last_day(@lastdate) - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY) as Day , DAYNAME(last_day(@lastdate) - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY) as DayName
    from (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as a
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as b
    cross join (select 0 as a union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9) as c
  where year(last_day(\'2024-12-31\') - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY)=year(@lastdate) and month(last_day(@lastdate) - INTERVAL (a.a + (10 * b.a) + (100 * c.a)) DAY)=month(@lastdate)
    order by Day) Y ON X.DAY=Y.DAY order by Y.DAY'
  );
PREPARE stmt 
FROM 
  @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

When there is data, it returns the following:
contains data image
When there isn't data, it returns:
no data image
What I would like to accomplish is:

remove second "DAY" column from the query
convert all nulls to 0

I tried:

to remove X or Y
to add ISNULL(column, 0)

This is not working.

Why are you using Dynamic-SQL here? This looks like it shouldn't need it...


Replace SELECT  Y.*,X.* in the output list with definite separate columns list. 2. Apply IFNULL (not ISNULL) in this output list.


@Dai maybe I over-complicated it, do you have a nicer solution?

FYI, you don't need to use CONCAT() inside GROUP_CONCAT(). If you give multiple arguments to GROUP_CONCAT() it automatically concatenates them.

@Dai Dynamic SQL is needed for the dynamic pivot in MySQL.

@Barmar I see that now, yes; though the query could be made more readable by moving the bulk of the query (currently in the string literal) to a CTE, with the GROUP_CONCAT being the final step to generate @sql.

@Akina I can select Y.*, ifnull(X.Total,0) as Total, but I don't know how to add the rest of the information...

You cannot continue to use select y.*, x.* because you get most nulls AFTER the right join of x with y, so the IFNULL(column,0)  [or better still COALESCE(coulmn,0)] is needed in final select list. i.e. IFNULLs in the sub-queries don't help solve the nulls issue in the final, combined, output.
